# GoDaddy forwarding for bare domain to www is not working for a .dev domain hosted by Blogger

Tags: dns, godaddy, blogger, no-www

I have a website (`example.dev`) registered with GoDaddy that only works when `www.` is prefixed to the URL. It is hosted at `ghs.google.com`, using Google's Blogger platform. In the Blogger settings I have activated a setting called "Redirect Domain" that redirects `example.dev` to `www.example.dev`. But whether that setting is on or not, my domain won't work without `www`.

In the GoDaddy DNS manager, I added forwarding from `example.dev` to `https://www.example.dev`, but it has been two days and nothing has changed. None of the solutions I found online have worked for me, but it seems that Blogger has some kind of quirk that causes this issue.

Comment: There is an `A` record on your apex name, so the problem is not at the resolution stage. Do remember that `.dev` TLD and hence all names below it, is in HSTS preloading list so browsers will only ever attempt HTTPS queries and not HTTP ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GoDaddy doesn't support HTTPS for forwarding redirects. You have a `.dev` domain which requires HTTPS. To redirect your bare domain to `www.`, you will need to use a different service that supports HTTPS.

Google added the entire `.dev` top level domain to the HSTS preload list. That means that browsers will refuse to communicate with any HTTP server for any `.dev` domain and will only talk to HTTPS servers.

The usual way to handle the bare domain to `www.` redirect is to use an `A` record to point the bare domain to the same web host as your `www.` subdomain. Then you can put rules in place on your web host to redirect the bare domain to `www.`.

According to [this article from Namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1243/2208/how-do-i-use-my-domain-with-my-blogger-account/), Blogger's IP addresses that can be used for `A` records are:

- `216.239.32.21`
- `216.239.34.21`
- `216.239.36.21`
- `216.239.38.21`